# Call id textarea with variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi i have this form opening with window's dialog:

```
<form method="GET" id="formparam">
<table><tbody><tr><td>
<label>ID</label></td>
<td><textarea style="height: 21px; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" class="expand" id="inputp8_id"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></form>
```

But when i push button's name's Add.Function's the script of code:

```
$("#wnd_Addparam").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Add": function() {
            contapara = (parseInt(contapara) + 1);
            var rok = $(#'inputp' + i + '_id').value;
            document.getElementById("sorpara").innerHTML += "<li id=\"inputp" + contapara + "_id\" class=\"ui-state-default\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s\"></span>" + rok + "</li>";

            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});

$("#btn_Addpar").click(function() {
    $("#wnd_Addparam").dialog("open");
});​
```

The variable's contapara is 5.
But why the value's variable is undefined or nothing or code's html (with .text)?
I look at the variable i and contapara are value is correct.
Where i am wrong in this `var rok =$(#'inputp'+i+'_id').value;` ?
How to call the id's textarea inputp6_id  and print the content?

Comment: The error is in var rok =$(#'inputp'+i+'_id').value;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below. This will get the value from within the textarea.

```
var contapara =(parseInt($(contapara).val())+1);
```

**edit:**

```
var rok =$('#inputp'+i+'_id').val();
```

The hash was also in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes i Look in the my inbox for who answered first

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var rok = $(#'inputp' + i + '_id').value;
```

to -

```
var rok = $('#inputp' + i + '_id').val();
```

actually I don't even know where you are getting `i` from - but this should work as long as `i` is defined

Answer (score 0):

Where do you actually define `contapara` in the first instance? You need to define a variable before you use its value.

i.e.

```
var contapara = 0;
```

Same goes for `i` - I cannot see where this is defined.

As pointed out in comments, the correct syntax is:

```
$('#inputp' + i + '_id').val();
```

If you are still having a problem, stick this in and see what comes out:

```
alert('#inputp' + i + '_id'); // is this what you expect?
$('#inputp' + i + '_id').val();
```

I expect you'll find that `i` isn't what you expect.

Comment: I before declare this variable....
 The error is in var rok =$(#'inputp'+i+'_id').value;

Comment: Try `$('#inputp' + i + '_id').value` - the `#` goes inside the quotes.

Comment: But `.value` is not a method of a jQuery object. It's `.val()`

Comment: @ianpgall correct. Funny just how many errors are in the original code!

Comment: Haha very true, it's not just one thing!